# How to secure my GeoJSON data?

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps, bing-maps, geojson

I am trying to create a website that display Google map mark up with my proprietary data (in form of multiple polygons) on top of it.
I have been studying Google Map API and found the only way to do it is to publish my proprietary data in GeoJSON file then use the following api function to load the data to Google map: map.data.loadGeoJson(xxxxxx);

This means I need to publish my proprietary data by web service in GeoJSON format. However, I don't want users to download my proprietary data and use it for another purpose  other than my site. This is similar to a website which allows video streaming but not allowing download the whole video offline.

How can I achieve the purpose? Can I use some language like PHP to generate the map (with markup) at server then send to web client in form of HTML? Or if I cannot achieve this by Google Map API, can other map API support it (like Bing?)

Thanks very much for your help!!!!

Code Mon key

Comment: If the data is viewable on a map, it has to be seen by the browser, which means someone who can view the web page can access that data.  The only way to make that more difficult would be to render the data as tiles on your server.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to turn your data into a tile layer. This will limit the user to only seeing an image of the data but would not give them access to the raw data. In a worse case scenario they would only be able to take the images and view the data and not do any kind of analytics against it unless they manually trace all the data.

As an added benefit of rendering the data as a tile layer, you will be able to visualize a lot more data. I've built a few systems that can render 500M rows of polygon data on a map using this approach. The cool thing, if you store the data in a spatial database like SQL Azure, you can easily make your data interactive by taking the point a user clicks on a map and searching the database for any shapes that intersect with that point.

I wrote a simple blog post on how to create a web service that does this many years ago here: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/dynamic-tile-layers-in-the-bing-maps-silverlight-control/

There is also a good open source project here that uses ASP.NET: http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/

I have a whitepaper that is a lot more up to date than my blog post that will be published soon. If you email me at ricky_brundritt at Hotmail.com, I'll send you a draft copy.